# Union type in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, types

Do you know if ActionScript support union type? For example, something like that:

```
function foo(x:ClassA Union classB) {
  //x is classA or classB 
  //do something
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not possible. Depending on what you're trying to do, using an interface would be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actionscript 3 does not support c++ style mixin class hierarchies.

As3 rather uses the **Interface** approach that is utilized in many object oriented languages.

An Interface generally is an abstract template of functionality allowing communication between objects which are unrelated in respect of class hierarchy.

such as:

```
public interface IBox{ 
   function addContentToBox(contentName:String, content:*) Boolean;
   function boxHasContent(contentName:String): Boolean;
   function getContentFromBox(contentName:String): *;  
}
```

When you define a class in as3, if you want it to implement IBox Interface you write

```
class YourClass extends anotherClass implements IBox {
```

(extends anotherClass is only needed if you are extending another class)

Now you have to write code for functions declared in **IBox** in **YourClass**.

Then what is the catch? Well, first of all

```
a = new YourClass(parameters etc);
if(a is YourClass)trace('YIPPE');
if(a is IBox)trace('YAY');
```

You have a trace of YIPPE YAY now.

(xxx is IBox) will be true for all instances of all classes implementing IBox.

You can pass any unrelated objects with classes implementing IBox to functions expecting IBox.

Please refer to [Adobe as3 interface document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html) for further information.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Closest you can get to that is by having a base class `A` and deriving two classes from it `B` and `C`. Then you can pass either `B` or `C` instances to the function `foo`.

```
class classA {}

class classB extends classA {}

class classC extends classA {}

function foo(x:ClassA)
{
    if(x is classB)
        trace("x is classB");
    else if (x is classC)
        trace("x is classC");
}

var c:ClassC = new ClassC();

foo(c);
```

Though I wouldn't suggest checking types of classes and executing code based on that, using an interface would probably help you out, but we would need to know what you are trying to do.